# My script runs as expected but eats up system resources when it is done

Tags: javascript

The script is for a countdown timer when it counts down to zero it is expected to stop which it does, but at that moment when it stops the browser hooks and my CPU starts approaching its peak

```
const countdown = () => {
  const startDate = new Date();
  const h = parseInt(document.querySelector("#hours").value);
  const m = parseInt(document.querySelector("#mins").value);
  const s = parseInt(document.querySelector("#seconds").value);
  const endDate = new Date(
    startDate.getFullYear(),
    startDate.getMonth(),
    startDate.getDate(),
    h,
    m,
    s
  );
  if (startDate.getHours() > h) {
    alert("Set time must be greater than current time");
  } else {
      const startDateMs = startDate.getTime();
      const endDateMs = endDate.getTime();
      let timeDiff = endDateMs - startDateMs;
      const stoptime = timeDiff;
      timeDiff = timeDiff / 1000;
      let secondsLeft = Math.floor(timeDiff % 60);
      timeDiff = timeDiff / 60;
      let minsLeft = Math.floor(timeDiff % 60);
      timeDiff = timeDiff / 60;
      let hoursLeft = Math.floor(timeDiff % 24);
      let timeLeft = `${hoursLeft} : ${minsLeft} : ${secondsLeft}`;
      document.querySelector("#showCountdown").innerHTML = timeLeft;
      document.title = `${timeLeft} Febi's Clock`;

      if (stoptime <= 0) {
        timeLeft = `00 : 00 : 00`;
        clearInterval(countdown);
        document.querySelector("#showCountdown").innerHTML = timeLeft;
        document.title = timeLeft;
      } else {
        setInterval(countdown, 1000);
      }
  }
};

document.getElementById("setTime").addEventListener(
  "submit",
  e => {
    countdown();
    e.preventDefault();
  },
  false
);
```

I want it to stop running once the countdown has expired.

Comment: You should be using `setTimeout()`, not `setInterval()`.

Comment: You don't pass a function to `clearInterval`. You pass a reference to the interval created by `setInterval`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the issue based on your comments